# All toggle open but only when code copy pasted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a problem with the Jquery toggle option. I copy-pasted the code of the first toggle block to use as a template for the next ones and it worked perfectly on the first page. I personalised 8 blocks that open and close when clicked. 
But when I copy-pasted some of those to put them on another page, they are all open by default. The same exact code gives a different outcome.

As suggested in other posts I tried changing the class and ID names, and over write with 'ready-hide' but it still won't make the toggle 'closed' by default.

How could I have the toggable blocks closed when the page opens?

I'm sorry for the gibberish, this is my first try at coding and I could really use a little help!

Thank you

Example of my code that works on one page but not the next one:

```
<div id="flip1" class="flip">
  <span style="cursor:pointer">
   <img src="img1"/><b>Title1</b>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="panel1" class="panel">
  <div class="type1">
   <article id="article1">
     <h2>Title first article</h2><img src="img"/>bla bla bla</article>
  </div>
</div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel1").hide();
    $("#flip1").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>


<div id="flip2" class="flip">
  <span style="cursor:pointer">
   <img src="img2"/><b>title2</b>
  </span>
</div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel">
  <div class="type2">
   <article id="article2">
    <h2>Title second article</h2><img src="img"/>Bla Bla bla Bla</article>
  </div>
</div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#panel2").hide();
    $("#flip2").click(function(){
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: This is a guess, but are you sure the other pages have jQuery included properly?  Check to see if there are any other JavaScript errors on the pages where it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Pat Thank you so much for your answer. I checked and it was indeed the jQuery that I didn't include properly. I feel sorry taking your time for such a stupid mistake... Thank you again!

Comment: No problem and don't beat yourself up - everyone makes dumb mistakes when they're starting up.  The longer you code, the less you make :)

Comment: @pat True! Thanks for everything :)